Migration from Spring (Vanilla) to Spring Boot - how to keep urls after custom servlet mapping?
I am migrating my very large web application that used Spring MVC (vanilla) to Spring Boot (version 3.2.5).
My application used to use a different framework as well, and as a result, I explicitly specified in the web.xml file which requests should be processed by Spring's DispatcherServlet, like this:
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.s</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

So, all requests with the suffix ".s" and ".json" were targeted to the Spring's DispatcherServlet.
In Spring Boot this is no longer possible, the "" for DispatcherServlet is set to "/". It doesn't bother me, I think it's the right policy. However, in my application there are very many references in content and code to urls with ".s" or ".json" suffix. E.g. "https://example.com/article.s?id={id}".
I would like to avoid having to rewrite all occurrences of "article.s" and the controller code for "article" and have the request from "article.s" served, as before, by the @Controller with @RequestMapping(value = "/article", params="id"). The similar problem is with ".json" controllers. Btw: in vanilla Spring, I didn't have to add ".s" or ".json" in the definition of @RequestMapping - Spring MVC was able to understand and ignore this suffix in the request url. This means that all controllers are defined like this: @RequestMapping(value = "/someurl" ...) and not like this: @RequestMapping(value = "/someurl.s"...)
How can I work around this?
Maybe using some url-rewrite mechanism (rewriting all requests to "someurl.s" / "someurl.json" to "someurl")?
Update
Sorry, I see that in an older version of Spring I used the setUseSuffixPatternMatch method in WebMvcConfigurer.configurePathMatch. In Spring 6 this method is deprecated and there is no replacement for it, will be removed soon.
public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
  configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(true);
}

I still can use it for some time, I guess. However, the "suffix pattern match" is way too much than I need. I am looking for a method to set the redirect from ".s" and ".json" to "*".

I found a solution, similar to the one in this discussion on Spring Github, regarding another deprecated option - "trailing slash match".
@Component
public class ServletRequestWrapperFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
     HttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request) {
            @Override
            public String getRequestURI() {
                String requestURI = super.getRequestURI();
                if (StringUtils.endsWith(requestURI, ".s")) {
                    return StringUtils.removeEnd(requestURI, ".s");
                }
                return requestURI;
            }
        };
        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
    }
}

There will soon be a new filter in Spring 6.2 that solves the "trailing slash match" problem, and "suffix pattern match" can probably be solved in a similar way.
